# Why does ld include sections in the output file that are not specified in the link command file?

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, ld

I am struggling to understand how to make ld (in the gcc arm embedded tool kit) do what I want:

just as an example, I have a couple of .o files I want to link. say I *only* want a section called .foo in the output. I put this in the command file link.ld:

```
SECTIONS{
  .foo : {*(.text)}
}
```

and go "ld -T link.ld file1.o fil2.o -o output.o"

then i use objdump on output.o and it simply contains *every* section that was in the input files (), and absolutely no section called .foo this is the most confusing part why is there no section in the output called .foo?

I have read this http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/gcc_docs/ld_3.html and it all seems straight foward, I just cannot understand why such a simple linker script does nowhere near what I want it to do.

I must be missing something extremely obvious; can someone explain how I can control exactly which sections appear in the output file and what they are called?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you cannot control that so easily - as you see. If you don't link some sections "explicitly" (in which case you have control over things like order, alignment, location, fill, ...), everything else that the linker finds necessary is just placed "after that". It's a simplification, but this mostly works like this.

I don't think there's a way to tell linker to include *ONLY* the section you requested. But there's a way to tell it to exclude some sections. But the problem is that you have to be explicit about the sections you want to exclude.

> 3.6.7 Output Section Discarding
>
> ...
>
> The special output section name `/DISCARD/` may be used to discard input sections. Any input sections
>   which are assigned to an output section named `/DISCARD/` are not
>   included in the output file.

Maybe something like this would work?

```
SECTIONS{
  .foo : {*(.text)}
  /DISCARD/ : {*(*)}
}
```

Comment: "I don't think there's a way to tell linker to include ONLY the section you requested" Then what is the point of the linker script? The thing that is driving me up the wall is that I also tried -gc-sections -print-gc-sections and it prints "removing unused section..." and these sections *still* appear in the output! these are sections that have no links/symbols with any other sections

Comment: There is another problem too: sometimes, seemingly randomly, sections specified consecutively in the linker script endup at the same address in the output file. This *has* to be a bug in ld: all I am doing is:

.=0x08000000
section1
section2

and section 2 ends up overlapping section 1. This nonsense is driving me mental I have spent 3 days trying to solve these issues with what should be the simplest toy example linker script

Comment: @Jesse - the point of linker script is to tell the linker how to order the data, so that code is in flash, vectors at at the beginning, variables are in ram and the copy of these variables is available in flash (for initialization). There's no bug in linker, trust me. Start with a complete linker script that works and step-by-step remove/modify its elements until either the output matches your expectations or it does something unexpected. Here's a simple script for STM32F1 - https://gist.github.com/FreddieChopin/3dee4b02b0ba9b9de518f30c14caa884 (generated by http://distortos.org/ )