# Create default sections in linker script

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, linker-scripts

I have a very simple linker script as follows:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 1M; /* Load the kernel at 1M */

    .text ALIGN (4K) : {
        *(.multiboot) /* the multiboot header */
        *(.text)
    }

    .data ALIGN (4K) : { *(.data) }

    .bss ALIGN (4K) : { *(.bss) *(COMMON) }
}
```

While this works for a very basic assembly project, when I add in C, I want to make sure that no important sections from that get left out.  The `readelf -S` output on some compiled C code shows at least a half dozen other sections that `gcc`'s output includes, not including the debug sections.

I would like these sections to be included at the end, but I don't want to have to write it for every section (which could vary depending on whether I'm using debug, as well as on the contents of the C code).

Is there a way to make `ld` include any extra input sections without specifying them explicitly in the linker script?

Comment: Try running gcc with the -v flag. This will make it print all the other commands it executes. You can find the invocation of ld there. You can then see what script it passes. Usually this script is a huge one but constant. You can take parts from it or use it as is.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I tried this, and it didn't actually invoke `ld` -- only `cc1`, `as`, and `collect2` (no `-T` or `--script` or `-dT` or `--default-script` options).  If I manually invoked `collect2` with `-v`, it didn't show any linker script there, either.

Comment: collect2 is actually calling the linker ld. If you want to see those too, you can copy paste the command that calls collect2 and add -v at the end. It will print the command that calls the linker ld.exe again copy that line and add --verbose at the end. You will see that the entire linker script itself is printed. Other way is to send --vebose to the linker directly from gcc using `gcc test.c -Wl,--verbose`. The -Wl flag is to forward arguments to linker.

Comment: Through some (not extensive) testing, and looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511317) I just found, it seems it will include any non-listed sections.  Thank you though, running with `--verbose` was helpful.